# Get JW Player to buffer frames before clicking play

Tags: javascript, video, jwplayer

I have a JS instance of JW Player and When i click play, there is a slight delay from clicking the play button to actually seeing video frames.  Is there any way to get rid of this delay (I guess by preloading the file or prebuffering frames)?  I am aware of the bufferlenght flashvar but As far as i know this is used to lengthen the time between pushing play and the video actually playing.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="movie-player">
<div class="mobile-vid" style="top: 0; width: 693; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;">
              <div id="mediaplayer2"></div>
              </div>

               <script type="text/javascript">
                jwplayer("mediaplayer2").setup({
                    flashplayer: "player.swf",
                    file: "hqvs12.mp4",
                    autostart: false,
                    height:"390",
                    width: "693",
                    controlbar: "none",
                    wmode: "transparent",
                    image: "preview_intro.png",
                    icons: false,
                    "controlbar.position": false
                });
               </script>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did to make sure the delay is the least possible was to do a seek to some random second and pause as soon as it tried to start playing.

```
    var preBufferDone = false;
    var pl=jwplayer('player').setup({
       file: '<video / audio file path>', 
       autostart: false,
       width: 200, 
       height: 30
    });
    pl.onReady(function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){pl.seek(1000)},500);
    });
    pl.onPlay(function(os){
        // if preBufferDone is not set, the player must be starting due to seek
        if (!preBufferDone) setTimeout(pl.pause, 100);
        preBufferDone = true;
    });
```

Hope that helps.